# Browser not saving response cookies

Tags: express, cookies, jwt, nestjs, setcookie

Frond-end: React (react-admin) with Webpack
Back-end: NestJS / Express

I developed 3 routes (login, check and logout) that are beautifully working with Swagger UI, but when I try to use the 'login' route in my login page it doesn't save the cookie in the browser > application > storage > cookies

I'm setting the cookie on the back end with this code:

```
response.cookie('tk', 'Bearer ' + token, {
    domain: hostname, // localhost or 127.0.0.1
    path: "/",
    expires: oneMonthFromNowDate,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: true
});
```

And in the front end I'm receiving a successfull response with the cookie assigned:

[image]

[image]

But it is not saving in the browser > application > storage > cookies!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was missing some kind of configuration...

Solved using Axios with "credentials: true" option.

Comment: Can you post an entire config which helped you solve this?